Soft transition between a network image frames with Python
I have developed a rewiring network whose edges shrink or expand depending on some factors. This way some nodes get closer when the conditions are met, and some others move away from each other under those conditions. The rewiring process is controlled by a loop, and each stage of the loop creates an image that forms part of the resulting final GIF.
I'm less than an absolute beginner in animation, frames, images and GIFs, so my results are very modest and my approach surely naïve. My original GIF can look like this, and as can be seen, the transition from one frame to the next is very abrupt, sharp:
The code I use for it was:
def generateGif():
    images = []
    nImages = len(os.listdir(f"./generatedImages/Network{networkNum}"))
    for iter in range(0, nImages):
        fileName = f"./generatedImages/Network{networkNum}/Random Network - {iter}.png"
        images.append(imageio.imread(fileName))
    
    create_folder("./generatedGif")
    nGifs = len(os.listdir("./generatedGif"))
    imageio.mimsave(f'./generatedGif/network{nGifs}.gif', images, fps=2)


Now, I have tried including a transition between frames, modifying the previous code, in the following way:
def generateGif():
    images = []
    nImages = len(os.listdir(f"./generatedImages/Network{networkNum}"))
    for iter in range(0, nImages):
        fileName = f"./generatedImages/Network{networkNum}/Random Network - {iter}.png"
        images.append(imageio.imread(fileName))
    
    # Perform smooth transition between frames
    blended_images = []
    num_frames = len(images)
    alpha_start= 0 
    alpha_end = 1
    
    for i in range(num_frames - 1):
        alpha = np.linspace(alpha_start, alpha_end, num=num_frames)[i]
        blended_image = alpha_blend(images[i], images[i+1], alpha)
        print('BLENDED IMAGES type and shape', blended_image.dtype, blended_image.shape)
        blended_images.append(blended_image)

    create_folder_if_non_existing("./generatedGif")
    nGifs = len(os.listdir("./generatedGif"))
    imageio.mimsave(f'./generatedGif/network{nGifs}.gif', blended_images, fps=2)

# Performs alpha blending between two frames to create a smooth transition effect.
def alpha_blend(image1, image2, alpha):
    blended_image = (1 - alpha) * image1 + alpha * image2
    blended_image = np.clip(blended_image, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
    return blended_image

However, the result is bad (not showing continuity for the nodes movement):

My goal is to approach to something like this superb movements and transitions (although I'm light years away from this excellence): social demo of echo chambers.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

You can't get animation like the one in your link with just frame blending – instead, you'll need to interpolate the node positions between two situations, and actually render the intermediate frames.
